# Access adding data from multiple tables

Tags: ms-access

I have multiple data tables and I want to add together some values.

```
Table1 
Item      units
xx        1
yy        2   
zz        3

Table2
Item      Units
xx        1
yy        2
zz        3

Table3
Item      Units
xx        1
yy        2
zz        3
```

What I need returned is basicly Totals

so

```
xx = 3
yy = 4
zz = 6
```

This has to be done with multiple tables. I am attempting to do this in Access and I have no idea how to start.

Edit:

How would I also get it to display an associated value?

For ex:

```
 Table1 
 Item       units       Associated Value
 xx         1           randomval1
 yy         2           randomval2

 Table2 
 Item       units       Associated Value
 xx         1           randomval1
 yy         2           randomval2
```

so then the resulting output should be

```
 xx randomval1 = 2
```

Is this do able?

Comment: Anyone can help with the modified question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create a SQL Request which will join your data and make a sum afterwards

```
SELECT Item, SUM(Units)
FROM (
    SELECT Item, Units 
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Item, Units 
    FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Item, Units 
    FROM Table3
) 
GROUP BY Item
```

Comment: +1. I posted a similar answer, but yours is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for that. That worked great. One more question how do I only display the value of another column... Like Title per say.

Comment: Title ? is it part of your tables? explain more what your are expecting

Comment: Yes there is a Title field as part of my tables. for ex

Item Title Units

And I just want to have title Displayed along with the Item